# How to place glyphicon inside bootstrap badge

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've been slowly building a way to show hierarchical data using bootstrap badges and AngularJS. I am trying to allow people to browse through categories to find whatever category they are looking for.

There are 3 generic types of categories:

parent              -     top level category

parent and child    -     child category with their own subcategories

child               -     bottom level child category with no sub-categories

So far, with the considerable help of you Stackoverflowers, I have a pretty nice looking version working that you can see here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5I1pU0TZo6AjHJTbBuG9

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<ul id="categoriesUnorderedList">
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories"
      ng-show="category.category_show"
      class="badge-slider">
    <span ng-click="categoryClicked(category)"
          class="badge {{ getBadgeClassName(category.category_type) }}"
          ng-style="getIndent(category)"> {{category.category_name}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently I am using different CSS classes to display each type with a different coloured badge. For example, below is the CSS used for the parent badge:

```
.badge-p {
    background-color:#005DB3;
  color:#f8f8f8;
  cursor: default;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.badge-p:hover {
    background-color:#116ec4;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Now I want to make all this a little more classy.

The plan is to add a glyphicon-plus-sign to the left side of the badge of the "parent" and the "parent and child" categories, signifying that there exists sub-categories for this category that are not yet opened.

This glyphicon would be changed to a glyphicon-minus-sign when the category has been clicked and sub-categories are displayed. It would, then change back to the glyphicon-plus-sign when the opened category is clicked again and closed.

This way, all categories would be displayed with the same colour, making things easier on the eye, and of course making the whole thing much more intuitive for the user.

What is the best way to do this? Also, is there a generic non-glyphicon way to do this - I may want to experiment with other icons for these symbols, in-case the glyphicons don't look the greatest....

**EDIT 1:** I've put together a fully working version using the help of ABr's answer, with slightly different HTML - the glyphicon was placed in a span within the span of the badge. This helped keep the text correctly positioned and sized within the badge, without the need for any extra CSS. The functionality has been implemented for all the categories.... Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/19ihMtyJsQwcuLxKhgQh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is by adding a seperate state (I used category.expand) in your category data. You can then use ng-class to toggle the right class.

Add a seperate (for aligning the glyphs a bit more easily) span with ng-class: `ng-class={{expandGlyphs}}`

Then define the expandGlyphs in your scope as follow:

```
$scope.expandGlyphs = "{
    'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign': !category.category_expand && (category.category_type == 'parent' || category.category_type == 'parent and child'), 
    'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign': category.category_expand && (category.category_type == 'parent' || category.category_type == 'parent and child')
}"
```

To align the glyphicons to the text add the following to your css:

```
/*Center Glyph*/
.glyphicon:before {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

I have made an example for the fruit category - [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1eeWpY?p=preview)

Note 1: Since you have everything hard coded (I would suggest you to rewrite your code a bit), it is up to you to do the same for the other categories.

If you want to have custom items, you can think about adding seperate css classes and assign them in the ng-class instead of the glyphicons. E.g.

```
.plus-sign:before {
  content: "+";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
.minus-sign:before {
  content: "-";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. One question though: the text on the badge seems to become much smaller and squashed to the bottom of the badge... what would be doing that, and how to prevent it from squashing the text?

Comment: I am not that well with CSS, but there are lots of topics on SO about styling and aligning which probably one of that will fit your question. You could also try to add the glyph to the list item instead of the span, but that might be not what you want.

Comment: Funny, I ran into the same issue myself. Solved it by changing the css. Edited my answer and the Plnkr with the changes.

Comment: I've found a nice solution myself - put the glyphicon stuff in a span inside the badge span! The show/hide code is extremely hard-coded, just because the real code is so complex, people would have great difficulty in following/making any necessary changes. You would think it would be simple, but when is it ever simple?? I've loaded up a new fully working plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/19ihMtyJsQwcuLxKhgQh